# SOLR: What does an autoSoftCommit maxtime of -1 mean?

Tags: solr

Here's the default setting from my solrconfig.xml file:

```xml
 <autoSoftCommit> 
   <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
 </autoSoftCommit>
```

Does the maxTime of '-1' mean that automatic soft commits are off? If so, would I get the same result if I deleted the tag altogether? And if I have to manually do the soft commits, can that be done with 'commitWithin' (I googled this but got conflicting answers)?

Oh, and I'm using Solr 4.5.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First off, you can see the expression `${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}` within the tag. This allows you to make use of Solr's **variable substitution**. That feature is described in detail [here in the reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+solrconfig.xml). If that variable has not been substituted by any of those means `-1` is taken as value for that configuration.

**Turning commitMaxTime  to -1** effectively turns autocommit off. If you have a look at the relevant code below, you can see that `commitMaxTime` overrules any value of `maxDocs`, as the scheduleCommitWithin method returns immediately. I have not found this behaviour documented, so I looked up the code.

```java
private void _scheduleCommitWithin(long commitMaxTime) {
    if (commitMaxTime <= 0) return;
    synchronized (this) {
      if (pending != null && pending.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <= commitMaxTime) {
        // There is already a pending commit that will happen first, so
        // nothing else to do here.
        // log.info("###returning since getDelay()==" + pending.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + " less than " + commitMaxTime);

        return;
      }

      if (pending != null) {
        // we need to schedule a commit to happen sooner than the existing one,
        // so lets try to cancel the existing one first.
        boolean canceled = pending.cancel(false);
        if (!canceled) {
          // It looks like we can't cancel... it must have just started running!
          // this is possible due to thread scheduling delays and a low commitMaxTime.
          // Nothing else to do since we obviously can't schedule our commit *before*
          // the one that just started running (or has just completed).
          // log.info("###returning since cancel failed");
          return;
        }
      }

      // log.info("###scheduling for " + commitMaxTime);

      // schedule our new commit
      pending = scheduler.schedule(this, commitMaxTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Taken from https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_5/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/CommitTracker.java

To the second part of your question, if you **remove the tag** all together this will have the same result as setting the value to -1. As you can see below, if the xpath expression returns null, you will get -1 as default value.

But removing the whole expression from the configuration will also remove the option to override that configuration via Solr's variable substitution.

```java
protected UpdateHandlerInfo loadUpdatehandlerInfo() {
  return new UpdateHandlerInfo(get("updateHandler/@class",null),
    getInt("updateHandler/autoCommit/maxDocs",-1),
    getInt("updateHandler/autoCommit/maxTime",-1),
    getBool("updateHandler/autoCommit/openSearcher",true),
    getInt("updateHandler/commitIntervalLowerBound",-1),
    getInt("updateHandler/autoSoftCommit/maxDocs",-1),
    getInt("updateHandler/autoSoftCommit/maxTime",-1),
    getBool("updateHandler/commitWithin/softCommit",true));
}
```

Taken from https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_5/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/core/SolrConfig.java