# Solr AutoCommit not working with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, solr, dataimporthandler, autocommit

I am using Solr 4.10.0 with PostgreSql 9.3. I am able to configure my solr core properly using data-config.xml and search through the database different tables. However, I am not able to setup the autoCommit feature. Whenever any row gets added in the table, I expect them to start appearing in the results after the maxTime (1 minute) but that doesn't happen. I have to explicitly rebuild the index by doing a full data-import and then everything works fine.

My solrconfig.xml is:

```
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

     <autoCommit>
       <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
       <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
     </autoCommit>

     <autoSoftCommit>
       <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
     </autoSoftCommit>

  </updateHandler>
```

Is there something extra needs to be done for using autoCommit here? I checked my log files as well but there is no error / exception. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link...

[SOLR: What does an autoSoftCommit maxtime of -1 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130788/solr-what-does-an-autosoftcommit-maxtime-of-1-mean)

I think this is what is happening in your case..

First off, you can see the expression ${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1} within the tag. This allows you to make use of Solr's variable substitution. That feature is described in detail here in the reference. If that variable has not been substituted by any of those means -1 is taken as value for that configuration.
Turning commitMaxTime to -1 effectively turns autocommit off.

Comment: I have already tried removing the autoSoftCommit tag altogether but didn't find any change in the behavior. Whether it is there or not, new documents don't get added to the index automatically.